# TabBar Controller on DetailViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have 5 pages and linked eachother with TabBarController. My last viewcontroller is called More and it is table viewcontroller. In this tableviewcontroller, many other viewcontrollers are linked to this tableviewcontroller such as like us, contact us, rate us etc.. I want to see main tabbar on these viewcontrollers also. How is it possible? I use storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simulate the tab bar in the viewcontrollers in your storyboard, have a look at the Attributes Inspector, section Simulated Metrics:

[image]

Instead of linking the MoreViewController to your TabController, link to  a NavigationController and set its rootViewController to the MoreViewController. Now you can easily navigate to your other tableviewcontrollers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652714/from-thirdviewcontroller-to-firstviewcontroller