# From Thirdviewcontroller to FirstViewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have two navigationviewcontroller in my story board.

Firstviewcontroller linked to firstnavigationcontroller. ThirdViewcontroller linked to second navigationcontroller. Then I want to know how to go from thirdviewcontroller to firstviewcontroller.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple ways to return to FirstViewController from ThirdViewController:

1. `[UINavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:]` method
2. Set up a storyboard unwind segue

This [post](http://chrisrisner.com/Unwinding-with-iOS-and-Storyboards) has more detailed examples.